# How to load apache poi libs in R?

Tags: java, r, apache-poi

I am trying to read word files into R in order to text parse them. After researching for a little while I found that Apache POI is the way to go for me, because it appears to be the most flexible w.r.t. handling different Word formats.

I tried to follow what the R packages `xlsx' or`commonJavaJars`and`xlsxjars` do. Unfortunately I was not able to create a few lines of R that work analogously. 
E.g.:

```
inputStream <- .jnew("java/io/FileInputStream", path.expand(file))

wbFactory <- .jnew("org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory")
```

What I do get from this, is that first an input stream is created (which i was able to do for a word fie as well). Then this Workbook Factory is created from the `apache poi library` using another .jnew. Looking for the a similar functionality for word I found [this part of the POI package](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/package-summary.html) and tried:

```
wdoc <- .jnew("org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument")
```

All i got is a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. POI packages other than Excel relevant packages should be available as there's a  `poi-3.9-20121203.jar` in the source code of `xlsxjars` which contains the .jars `xlsx` depends on.

Also tried to use the package `commonJavaJars` and ran the function

loadJars("poi")

without an error, but did not succeed with subsequent calls. Can someone get me started here?

EDIT: 
I obviously miss a package here. Can I instantly load additional `jars` into my R session or do I have to compile a package to add new jars?

Comment: so you are able to read an xlsx using poi but not word document?

Comment: I am able to read an xlsx using the r package xlsx which makes use of POI. So yes, I am able to read xlsx using POI, but I don't get why it's not working for HWPFDocument. Just believe there's some really dumb error I couldn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI provides [a handy page of the POI components, their jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). If you look on that, you'll see that to use HWPF you need *both* the main poi jar *and* the poi-scratchpad jar

So, assuming you're sticking with poi-3.9 (and not using the latest version, which is 3.10 beta 2 as of writing), you'll need to list `poi-3.9-20121203.jar` and `poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar` on your classpath. Once both are there, you should be fine to use HWPF

Since you're using R, if you decide to use the [CommonJavaJars library](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/CommonJavaJars) you should refer to the [R loadJars documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/CommonJavaJars/docs/loadJars) for details about how to load all of the jars you need in one go.

Alternately, if you want to skip CommonJavaJars and do it all by hand, then the following snippet shows how to to extract the text from a Word Document from R. Note - it's not pretty, because the R Java interface is decidedly low level...

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath("poi-3.10-beta3-20131022.jar")
.jaddClassPath("poi-scratchpad-3.10-beta3-20131022.jar")

inputStream <- .jnew("java/io/FileInputStream", path.expand("test.doc"))
wdoc <- .jnew("org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument", 
              .jcast(inputStream,"java/io/InputStream"))
wext <- .jnew("org/apache/poi/hwpf/extractor/WordExtractor", wdoc)

text <- .jcall(wext, "Ljava/lang/String;", "getText")
print(text)
```

If you want to use other components of Apache POI, be sure to look at the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to review any dependencies for them (some have more than others)

Comment: thanks, I thought I was missing something here. You're talkin to a java rookie here. How can load the additional `poi-scratchpad` in R?
The `loadJars` functions does not seem to be frequently used. I don't get how R packages like xlsx load their jars. sure there's a jar folder but are they only made available to R when the package is compiled? Do I have to build a package or can I just instantly load jars in my session?

Comment: `loadJars("poi-3.10")` works without error but `.jnew("org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument")` gives back a not found exception again.

Comment: You need *both* poi-xxx and poi-scratchpad-xxx for HWPF, as explained in the answer...

Comment: Ok seems like I am getting there at least the exception changes:
`loadJars("poi")` loadJars("poi-scratchpad") and .jnew("org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument")` led to
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIDocument

Comment: I don't know r, but `loadJars` sounds plural to me - can you not give it a list of the ones you want?

Comment: Indeed you're right `loadJars("poi","poi-scratchpad")` is possible, same exception though...

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/CommonJavaJars/docs/loadJars) loadJars returns some info, can you check that to see what it think it found / loaded?

Comment: I can't get loadJars to work, so I've added some code to do without it, which works for me!

Comment: Works for me now as well, thanks a lot for your patience. Low level is fine here, it's much more transparent than the entirely undocumented `loadJars`. Happy to skip it. The major problem was that `.jaddClassPath` is not giving any feedback so I did not know what was loaded. Like your solution for .doc, but recommend the XML R package for .docx